# Filling continuous pandas dataframe from sparse dataframe

Tags: python, python-2.7, pandas

I have a dictionary name date_dict keyed by datetime dates with values corresponding to integer counts of observations. I convert this to a sparse series/dataframe with censored observations that I would like to join or convert to a series/dataframe with continuous dates. The nasty list comprehension is my hack to get around the fact that pandas apparently won't automatically covert datetime date objects to an appropriate DateTime index.

```
df1 = pd.DataFrame(data=date_dict.values(),
                   index=[datetime.datetime.combine(i, datetime.time()) 
                          for i in date_dict.keys()],
                   columns=['Name'])
df1 = df1.sort(axis=0)
```

This example has 1258 observations and the DateTime index runs from 2003-06-24 to 2012-11-07.

```
df1.head()
             Name
Date
2003-06-24   2
2003-08-13   1
2003-08-19   2
2003-08-22   1
2003-08-24   5
```

I can create an empty dataframe with a continuous DateTime index, but this introduces an unneeded column and seems clunky. I feel as though I'm missing a more elegant solution involving a join.

```
df2 = pd.DataFrame(data=None,columns=['Empty'],
                   index=pd.DateRange(min(date_dict.keys()),
                                      max(date_dict.keys())))
df3 = df1.join(df2,how='right')
df3.head()
            Name    Empty
2003-06-24   2   NaN
2003-06-25  NaN  NaN
2003-06-26  NaN  NaN
2003-06-27  NaN  NaN
2003-06-30  NaN  NaN
```

Is there a simpler or more elegant way to fill a continuous dataframe from a sparse dataframe so that there is (1) a continuous index, (2) the NaNs are 0s, and (3) there is no left-over empty column in the dataframe?

```
            Name
2003-06-24   2
2003-06-25   0
2003-06-26   0
2003-06-27   0
2003-06-30   0
```

Answer (score 23, accepted):

You can just use reindex on a time series using your date range. Also it looks like you would be better off using a TimeSeries instead of a DataFrame (see [documentation](http://pandas.pydata.org/pandas-docs/stable/timeseries.html)), although reindexing is also the correct method for adding missing index values to DataFrames as well.

For example, starting with:

```
date_index = pd.DatetimeIndex([pd.datetime(2003,6,24), pd.datetime(2003,8,13),
        pd.datetime(2003,8,19), pd.datetime(2003,8,22), pd.datetime(2003,8,24)])

ts = pd.Series([2,1,2,1,5], index=date_index)
```

Gives you a time series like your example dataframe's head:

```
2003-06-24    2
2003-08-13    1
2003-08-19    2
2003-08-22    1
2003-08-24    5
```

Simply doing

```
ts.reindex(pd.date_range(min(date_index), max(date_index)))
```

then gives you a complete index, with NaNs for your missing values (you can use `fillna` if you want to fill the missing values with some other values - see [here](http://pandas.pydata.org/pandas-docs/stable/missing_data.html#missing-data-fillna)):

```
2003-06-24     2
2003-06-25   NaN
2003-06-26   NaN
2003-06-27   NaN
2003-06-28   NaN
2003-06-29   NaN
2003-06-30   NaN
2003-07-01   NaN
2003-07-02   NaN
2003-07-03   NaN
2003-07-04   NaN
2003-07-05   NaN
2003-07-06   NaN
2003-07-07   NaN
2003-07-08   NaN
2003-07-09   NaN
2003-07-10   NaN
2003-07-11   NaN
2003-07-12   NaN
2003-07-13   NaN
2003-07-14   NaN
2003-07-15   NaN
2003-07-16   NaN
2003-07-17   NaN
2003-07-18   NaN
2003-07-19   NaN
2003-07-20   NaN
2003-07-21   NaN
2003-07-22   NaN
2003-07-23   NaN
2003-07-24   NaN
2003-07-25   NaN
2003-07-26   NaN
2003-07-27   NaN
2003-07-28   NaN
2003-07-29   NaN
2003-07-30   NaN
2003-07-31   NaN
2003-08-01   NaN
2003-08-02   NaN
2003-08-03   NaN
2003-08-04   NaN
2003-08-05   NaN
2003-08-06   NaN
2003-08-07   NaN
2003-08-08   NaN
2003-08-09   NaN
2003-08-10   NaN
2003-08-11   NaN
2003-08-12   NaN
2003-08-13     1
2003-08-14   NaN
2003-08-15   NaN
2003-08-16   NaN
2003-08-17   NaN
2003-08-18   NaN
2003-08-19     2
2003-08-20   NaN
2003-08-21   NaN
2003-08-22     1
2003-08-23   NaN
2003-08-24     5
Freq: D, Length: 62
```

Comment: Thanks! I used 
    ts.reindex(pd.date_range(min(date_index), max(date_index)),fill_value=0)