# How to fill missing timestamps in pandas

Tags: python, pandas

I have a CSV file as below:

```
                  t  dd  hh  v.amm  v.alc  v.no2  v.cmo   aqi
0      201811170000  17   0   0.40   0.41   1.33   1.55  2.45
1      201811170002  17   0   0.40   0.41   1.34   1.51  2.46
2      201811170007  17   0   0.40   0.37   1.35   1.45  2.40
```

Now I have to fill in the missing minutes by last observation carried forward. Expected output:

```
                  t  dd  hh  v.amm  v.alc  v.no2  v.cmo   aqi
0      201811170000  17   0   0.40   0.41   1.33   1.55  2.45
1      201811170001  17   0   0.40   0.41   1.33   1.55  2.45
2      201811170002  17   0   0.40   0.41   1.34   1.51  2.46
2      201811170003  17   0   0.40   0.41   1.34   1.51  2.46
2      201811170004  17   0   0.40   0.41   1.34   1.51  2.46
2      201811170005  17   0   0.40   0.41   1.34   1.51  2.46
2      201811170006  17   0   0.40   0.41   1.34   1.51  2.46
3      201811170007  17   0   0.40   0.37   1.35   1.45  2.40
```

I tried following this [link](https://stackoverflow.com/questions/42673064/adding-missing-time-in-pandas-dataframe) but unable to achieve the expected output. Sorry I'm new to coding.

Answer (score 3, accepted):

First create `DatetimeIndex` by [`to_datetime`](http://pandas.pydata.org/pandas-docs/stable/reference/api/pandas.to_datetime.html) and [`DataFrame.set_index`](http://pandas.pydata.org/pandas-docs/stable/reference/api/pandas.DataFrame.set_index.html) and then change frequency by [`DataFrame.asfreq`](http://pandas.pydata.org/pandas-docs/stable/reference/api/pandas.DataFrame.asfreq.html):

```
df['t'] = pd.to_datetime(df['t'], format='%Y%m%d%H%M')
df = df.set_index('t').sort_index().asfreq('Min', method='ffill')
print (df)
                     dd  hh  v.amm  v.alc  v.no2  v.cmo   aqi
t                                                            
2018-11-17 00:00:00  17   0    0.4   0.41   1.33   1.55  2.45
2018-11-17 00:01:00  17   0    0.4   0.41   1.33   1.55  2.45
2018-11-17 00:02:00  17   0    0.4   0.41   1.34   1.51  2.46
2018-11-17 00:03:00  17   0    0.4   0.41   1.34   1.51  2.46
2018-11-17 00:04:00  17   0    0.4   0.41   1.34   1.51  2.46
2018-11-17 00:05:00  17   0    0.4   0.41   1.34   1.51  2.46
2018-11-17 00:06:00  17   0    0.4   0.41   1.34   1.51  2.46
2018-11-17 00:07:00  17   0    0.4   0.37   1.35   1.45  2.40
```

Or use [`DataFrame.resample`](http://pandas.pydata.org/pandas-docs/stable/reference/api/pandas.DataFrame.resample.html) with [`Resampler.ffill`](http://pandas.pydata.org/pandas-docs/stable/reference/api/pandas.core.resample.Resampler.ffill.html):

```
df['t'] = pd.to_datetime(df['t'], format='%Y%m%d%H%M')
df = df.set_index('t').sort_index().resample('Min').ffill()
```

Comment: KeyError: 't'
`df = pd.read_csv ('data.csv', index_col="t")`
Am I doing it wrong?

Comment: @Joey - Only use `df = pd.read_csv ('data.csv')` and then apply solution, `t` is column name, if different check `print (df.columns.tolist()`

Comment: I tried again and got ValueError: index must be monotonic increasing or decreasing. Sorry for the trouble.
The solution works when using DataFrame.resample!

Comment: @Joey - No problem, try sorting before `asfreq` or `resample`, answer was edited. Also check if datetimes are converted correctly.